# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1 | Pattern matching

Tags: java, regex, scala

I am trying to extract the value of version from `Accept` header which can be of the form

```
"vnd.example-com.foo+json; version=1.1"
```

here is my code for extracting the version

```
val resourceVersionPattern: Pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=version=).*")

def getResourceVersion(acceptHeader: String): String = {
            import java.util.regex.Matcher
            val matcher: Matcher = resourceVersionPattern.matcher(acceptHeader)
            if(matcher.find()) ("v" + matcher.group(1)).trim() else "v1.0"
    }
```

When I am invoking the above function which is intended to extract version (for example can be of the form v1.0 or v1.5 or v2.5)

```
 getResourceVersion("vnd.example-com.foo+json; version=1.1")
```

I get following exception:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1
at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:487)
at .getResourceVersion(<console>:12)
at .<init>(<console>:11)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at .<init>(<console>:11)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at $print(<console>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:704)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request$$anonfun$14.apply(IMain.scala:920)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.Line$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(Line.scala:43)
at scala.tools.nsc.io.package$$anon$2.run(package.scala:25)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I think I am doing something wrong in my regex or the input string has some illegal charecters which I am not able to identify with my limited knowledge of Regular expression. Help me find out the reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It'd advise against (ab)using look-behind, if it is possible to write one without that is clear and does the same thing.

Just use the pattern:

```
version=(.*)
```

And what you want will be in capturing group 1.

Answer (score 1):

The code is using lookbehind assertion:

```
(?<=version=)
```

That is not captured as a group. If you want capture `version=` as a group, use capturing group:

```
(version=)
```

To get `1.1` from the given string input, use following regular expression:

```
(?<=version=)(.*)
```

Comment: After modifying the pattern as (?<=(version=)) what I get after making the call getResourceVersion("vnd.example-com.foo+json; version=1.1") is `vversion=` not `v1.1`. I want to extract the version number and add `v` as a prefix to it. Is my pattern correct?

Comment: @VaibhavRaj, Try `(?<=version=)(.*)`.

Answer (score 0):

Surround the part you want to capture with parentheses to create a group (Actually, this is optional in your case since you want the entire matching area):

```
Pattern.compile("(?<=version=)(.*)")
```

Then use `matcher.group()` (with no parameter) to return `1.1` for your example input.

Note that you must call `matcher.find()` before using `matcher.group()`.

`matcher.group(x)` will only work if your regexp matches the *entire* input string.

Comment: Simply changing `group(1)` to `group()` will fix the problem; you don't need to add any parentheses.  `group()` is equivalent to `group(0)`, which returns everything that was consumed by the match.  (The "version=" part is not consumed because it was matched in a lookbehind.)  But [nhahtdh's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21485276/20938) is better.

Comment: @AlanMoore You're right, that's what I was trying to say but was not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code u r looking for...

void versionFinder() 
{

```
    String version = "vnd.example-com.foo+json; version=1.1";
    String regex = "(?<=(version=))(\\d((\\.)(\\d)+)?)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(version);
    int i=0;

    while (m.find()) {

        System.out.println(i+"-----------"+m.group() +"-------"+m.start());
        int j = m.start();
        String printable ="";
        while(j!=version.length() && version.charAt(j)!=' ')
                    {
            printable+=version.charAt(j);
            j++;
        }
        printable="v"+printable;
        System.out.println(printable);
        i++;
    }
```

}

You can change the regex after \d as per ur need.

Comment: "(?<=(version=))(\\d((\\.)(\\d)+)?)"  this one is better one work for all type string 
1. version=1.asdfa      2. version=1.234asaf
3. version=1.1          4. version=1.1 afasd